# Is it recommended to run WSO2 ESB on Windows for production?

Tags: windows, wso2, production-environment, wso2-esb

Has someone some experience by running WSO2 ESB on Windows for the production environment ? Is it officially support by WSO2 ? Is it recommended ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Performance+Tuning
This section describes some recommended performance tuning configurations to optimize the ESB. It assumes that you have set up the ESB on a server running **Unix/Linux**, which is **recommended** for a production deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the tested/compatible Operating systems [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/compatibility/Tested+Operating+Systems). For some versions, it may not be tested on a windows version, but having not tested doesn't imply that it's not compatible.